# Angular2 or NodeJs: Rearrange/Sort JSON elements based on another array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular

I have seen similar question but most answers are not with good performance. I would like to achieve this either using Angular2 or NodeJS whichever would be of a better performance.

I have a set of user fruit preferences' IDs

```
{15, 43, 55, 67, 98};
```

I have a JSON object with what fruits a supermarket offers

```
{"fruits":[
    {"Name":"Apple", "ID": 23},
    {"Name":"Mango", "ID": 15},
    {"Name":"Orange", "ID": 21},
    {"Name":"Melon", "ID": 7},
    {"Name":"Grapes", "ID": 67},
    {"Name":"Berries", "ID": 80},
]};
```

I need to rearrange efficiently the second list to have whatever exists in the first array at the top of the list, the rest of the elements I don't care about their order. So in the example above, the result should be

```
{"fruits":[
    {"Name":"Mango", "ID": 15},
    {"Name":"Grapes", "ID": 67},
    {"Name":"Apple", "ID": 23},
    {"Name":"Orange", "ID": 21},
    {"Name":"Melon", "ID": 7},
    {"Name":"Berries", "ID": 80},
]};
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an API request

```
[GET] api/fruits?id=5,43,55,67,98
```

I'm going to assume you meant those Ids were an array.

```
let ids = [5, 43, 55, 67, 98];
```

I'm assuming from this stand point your querying from somewhere.

```
var data = {"fruits":[
    {"Name":"Apple", "ID": 23},
    {"Name":"Mango", "ID": 15},
    {"Name":"Orange", "ID": 21},
    {"Name":"Melon", "ID": 7},
    {"Name":"Grapes", "ID": 67},
    {"Name":"Berries", "ID": 80},
]};
```

**Update**

```
var missing = [];
var result = data.fruits.filter(fruit => keys.indexOf(fruit.ID) > -1 
    ? true : missing.push(fruit) && false );
result.push(missing);

return { "fruits": result };
```

That's how you can query in Javascript.

I'd suggest using a Mongo store and camelCase for your properties names.

Comment: Thanks Proximo, your assumptions are correct, but wouldn't that just filter them and return only the common fruits/IDs? Or will the output be like in my post, all the fruits but the common ones at the top?

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed that part and assumed too much. Updating my answer.